# Track of added input types in jquery for validation

Tags: jquery, validation, plugins, jquery-validate

Sample view:

```
<td id='sample'>
<input type='text' id='names' name='names[]'/>
</td>
```

Say i added a button to add further inputs,

```
$("#sample").append("<input type='text' id='names' name='names[]'/>");
```

How would i then validate each input types added that they are required.

```
rules: { names: "required" }, messages: { names: "This is a required field." }
```

EDIT: should i add [] to the id asweel to make it an array so all names[] field would fall under the names rules.

Comment: I don't think the "[]" is valid in the name or the id field.  What is the purpose of it?  And I'm not sure what you mean when you say "Added a button" but show code adding another text field.

Comment: The [] in the name i used to contain all the datas as array.

for example, if a user inputs 5 fields with names as 'names[]'

in my server side code, if i do $_POST['names'] it would return an array of the values of those 5 fields in order from first field to the last. top to bottom i guess.

Comment: When i mentioned added a button, i assumed you understood what i mean.

A click trigger event of the jquery to append inside the td whenever i click the button lets say button id='click' so $("#click").click

Comment: Nice, I learned something new that could be useful!  Thanks for that :-)  Good luck with the validation!

Comment: And there could be issues with the id… you can't have more than one DOM element sharing the same id.  Does it even need an id?  I'm not sure if jquery validate needs it.  Do you need the id for anything?  You might need to re-run the jquery validation initializer for new inputs, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

This will validate each text box having names[]

`rules: { "names[]": "required" }, messages: { required: "This is a required field." }`

Comment: I will try this later, im not on my laptop with my php.

Ill accept this asap.

Comment: @user3432132 ok.it will work for me i tried with checkboxes in my project

Comment: Was thinking of the same, i assumed it has an effect same with names where it treats fields as a group whenever i $_POST the values.

Answer (score 0):

To put the rules for while creating the dynamic elements.
Let assume adding element when click the Add button.

```
...
...
<td id='sample'>
<input type='text' id='names' name='names[]'/>
</td>
...
...
<input type='button' id='add' value='Add' />
...
...

<script>

var count=1;

$('#add').click(function() {
  var newElement = $("<input type='text' id='names"+count+"' name='names[]'/>");
  $('#sample').append(newElement);

  newElement.rules('add', {
                required: true,
                messages: {
                    required: 'This field is required'
                }
            });
   count++;
});
</script>
```

Comment: replace count just trigger the click event

Comment: I was thinking of not having to add counter variables to the names, it only makes it confusing, plus, in my server side id have to loop through the fields to get the values. Instead, i use [] to get it all as an array.

Comment: If you are not using counter variable means, the dynamic elements all are in same id. It takes you misleading dynamic DOM elements. Do you want any manipulations at client side on dynamic elements?

Comment: I do, but i am aiming for a more efficient way and i think i already know that way.